# how can I add a calculated column that would show the total # of matching rows in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: ms-access, relationship, one-to-many, ms-access-2013, calculated-columns

I have two tables with a one-to-many relationship. I wanted to create a calculated column Table1 that shows the # of rows in Table2 like below.

How would I do this with MS Access? I know I can use a query but I was hoping to show it in the table itself.

```
╔═════════════════════════════╗
║ Table1                      ║
╠════╦══════╦═════════════════╣
║ ID ║ name ║ count in Table2 ║
╠════╬══════╬═════════════════╣
║  1 ║ a    ║               1 ║
║  2 ║ b    ║               4 ║
║  3 ║ c    ║               1 ║
║  4 ║ d    ║               3 ║
║  5 ║ e    ║               1 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════════════════╝


╔══════════════════════════╗
║ Table2                   ║
╠════╦═════════╦═══════════╣
║ ID ║  name   ║ Table1 ID ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ alpha   ║         2 ║
║  2 ║ bravo   ║         4 ║
║  3 ║ charlie ║         4 ║
║  4 ║ delta   ║         3 ║
║  5 ║ dingo   ║         2 ║
║  6 ║ mango   ║         2 ║
║  7 ║ pancake ║         1 ║
║  8 ║ banana  ║         2 ║
║  9 ║ cookie  ║         5 ║
║ 10 ║ fart    ║         4 ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering for future reference but this is not possible. A calculated column in MS Access cannot use a query and none of the available functions can be used to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use sub queries. something like this:

```
select id, [name], (select count(*) from table2 where table1.id = table2.table1_id) as [count in table2] from table1
```

Comment: but how do I use a sub-query in the table design view for a calculated column?

Comment: either write it like 
column_name: (slect .......from...)
or open up new design window create the subquery, copy and paste within a () ;) @IMTheNachoMan

Comment: That approach is fine as a field expression in a query.  But not as the expression for a calculated column in table design.  It can't reference another table.

Comment: Understood. So it sounds like this cannot be done. Thanks!

Comment: I'm such stupid... totally missed the core of your question LOL. no access tables cannot have sub queries in the table definition @IMTheNachoMan

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Access 2010 to test this with, but one possible avenue would be the domain function `DCount` (https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/DCount-Function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3):

In the calculated field expression you could use:

```
DCount("*","Table2","[Table1 ID]=" & [Table1].[ID])
```

This works in a query:

```
SELECT
    Table1.*,
    DCount("*","Table2","[Table1 ID]=" & [Table1].[ID]) AS ForeignCount
FROM Table1;
```

However, I think this is one of those cases where you should look beyond whether you could and consider whether you should.  Calculated fields do not belong in tables, they belong in queries or the presentation layer.

Comment: I already answered this and we confirmed it doesn't work in 2010 or 2013, so I deleted the answer. ugh.

Comment: Ugh, indeed.  I'll leave this post up so future viewers know it was tried and confirmed unsuccessful.